# apache rewrite rule not working

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /stylesheets/[0-9]+/(.*)$      /stylesheets/$1 [L]
```

So in the html I can say /stylesheets/05282011/xxx.css and it points to /stylesheets/xxx.css

This looks correct to me but can anyone spot why it wouldn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is starting slash `/` because that is stripped by Apache. Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^stylesheets/[0-9]+/(.*)$  /stylesheets/$1 [L]
```